# Can't change Button color by clicking it, every Button was created by a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

We want to change the color of the button when clicked, but the problem is that it only changes the color of the last button, because we created them all with a function.
The question would be if there is any option to fix this problem?

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.title("HANGMAN")
main.configure(width="800", height="400")
main.geometry("800x800")

def check(Event):
    lbutton.config(state="disabled", background="red")

def letter(x, gc, gr):
    global lbutton
    c = "lightblue"
    lbutton = Button(frame2, text = x, width="3", height="2", bg=c, activebackground="lightblue")
    lbutton.grid(row=gr,column=gc)
    return lbutton

main.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
frame1 = Frame(main, width="600",height="600")
frame1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
frame2 = Frame(main,bg="grey",width="200")
frame2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

letter("A", 1, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("B", 2, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("C", 3, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("D", 4, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("E", 5, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("F", 6, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("G", 7, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("H", 8, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("I", 9, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("J", 10, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("K", 11, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("L", 12, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("M", 13, 0).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("N", 1, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("O", 2, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("P", 3, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("Q", 4, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("R", 5, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("S", 6, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("T", 7, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("U", 8, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("V", 9, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("W", 10, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("X", 11, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("Y", 12, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)
letter("Z", 13, 1).bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", check)

main.mainloop()
```

We are unable to fix the problem, because there is no such information on the web.
We would appreciate if you could help us.

Comment: After all those years it's just embarrassing, sorry guys. :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `letter()` assigns each button to the same variable name so naturally the last button assigned will be the only one that can be edited as all previous assignments have been overwritten.

I would use a `list` to store your buttons and reference them per index.
In this case you do not need to bind the buttons when you can simply write a lambda function into the command argument of the button.

By working with the list to edit the button directly we can also work with the letter being selected by referencing the buttons `['text']` in the same `check` function and then do some work with that letter for your hangman game.

Notice the below code is roughly 20 lines shorter than your code because we manage the `bind` or `command` within a loop instead of line by line. This is accomplished by simply iterating over a string of the upper case alphabet and using `enumerate` to get an index value of the list that can directly translate to the same index of the list used to store the buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
btn_list = []
root.title("HANGMAN")
root.geometry("800x800")


def check(ndex):
    # Index used to work with the button directly in list
    btn_list[ndex].config(state="disabled", background="red")
    # example to show we can get the letter from the buttons text field.
    print(btn_list[ndex]['text'])


def create_buttons():
    row = 0  # tracking the row for our grid statement
    col = 1  # tracking the column for our grid statement
    for ndex, char in enumerate('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
        btn_list.append(tk.Button(frame2, text=char, width="3", height="2", bg="lightblue",
                                  activebackground="lightblue", command=lambda ndex=ndex: check(ndex)))
        btn_list[-1].grid(row=row, column=col)
        # Simple math to manage button placement for row and column
        if col <= 12:
            col += 1
        else:
            col = 1
            row += 1


frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width="600", height="600")
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="grey", width="200")
frame1.grid(row=0, sticky='e')
frame2.grid(row=1, sticky='e')
create_buttons()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: What "Your loop"?

Comment: @martineau oh. well guess there isn't one. For some reason when I looked at their function `letter()` I thought it was a loop but its just called allot on 26 different lines. I will edit that portion of my answer.

Comment: That's better. Using a loop would actually have been a better approach (like your answer does), and my first thought from the title of the question was that it was going to be the common `tkinter` problem that occurs when using one.

Comment: @martineau ya I sometimes confuse my words and miss them in proof reading before I post. I often have to edit my answer 2 or 3 times after posting to fix wording and typos.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix is to use `event.widget` in your function `check` instead:

```
def check(event):
    event.widget.config(state="disabled", background="red")
```

Comment: I would argue they need to use a loop for the bindings or even just use a lambda command in the buttons instead of writing 26 lines of binds.

Comment: Agreed, let’s just say I can’t resist pointing out the most obvious fix :)

Comment: @HenryYik true. That would at the very lest get it working even with the very redundant code :D